# Initialising and interacting with class in separate switch-case statements

Tags: java, class, methods, switch-statement

I am currently trying to learn java.

To my current knowledge, I understand it is an OO-based language. I am trying to create a simple class "Circle" with basic parameters (radius, area).

Main function:

```
import java.util.*;

public class CircleApp
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int choice = 1;
        while (choice!=4)
        {
            System.out.println("==== Circle Computation =====");
            System.out.println("|1. Create a new circle      |");
            System.out.println("|2. Print Area               |");
            System.out.println("|3. Print circumference      |");
            System.out.println("|4. Quit                     |");
            System.out.println("=============================");
            Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            choice = sc1.nextInt();
            switch (choice)
            {
                case 1:
                {
                    int rad;
                    System.out.println("Enter the radius to compute the area and circumference: \n");
                    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    rad = sc2.nextInt();
                    Circle circ1 = new Circle(rad);
                    circ1.setRadius(rad);
                    circ1.area();
                    circ1.printArea(circ1);
                    break;
                }
                case 2:
                {
                    circ1.area();
                    Circle.printArea(circ1);
                    break;
                }
                case 4:
                {
                    break;
                }
                default:
                {
                    System.out.println("Choice unknown");
                }
            }
        }
        

    }
    
}
```

Circle class:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Circle
{
    private double radius; // radius of circle
    private double area;
    private double circumference;
    private static int numCircle;
    private static final double PI = 3.14159;
    // constructor
    public Circle(double rad)
    {
        this.radius = rad;
        numCircle++;
    }
    public Circle()
    {
        radius = 1.0;
    }
    // mutator method – set radius
    public void setRadius(double rad)
    {
        this.radius = rad;
    }
    // accessor method – get radius
    public double getRadius()
    {
        return this.radius;
    }
    // calculate area
    public double area()
    {
        return area =  PI * Math.pow(radius, 2);
    }
    // calculate circumference
    public double circumference()
    {
        return circumference = 2 * PI * radius;
    }
    // print area
    public static void printArea(Circle c)
    {
        System.out.println("Radius: " + c.radius);
        System.out.println("Area: " + c.area);
    }
    // print circumference
    public void printCircumference()
    {
        System.out.println("Radius: " + radius);
        System.out.println("Circumference: " + circumference);
    }
}
```

Currently, I am trying to create an instance of class Circle within case 1 of my switch case. However, I am unable to get case 2 (calculate and print area) to run properly. While there is the simple workaround of initialising the object outside the switch case, I was wondering if there is a workaround if I were to initialise the object this way instead.

I understand from other sources that the compiler may not respond well to such a scenario as the initialisation of the object is isolated to case 1, which is not guaranteed to be selected first either. Is there a work-around to the issue I am facing or must I initialize the object outside the switch case? Thank you!

Comment: Your design doesn't make much sense. What do you expect to happen if I were to choose 2 without choosing 1 first?

Comment: Alternatively, you can check if the circle has already been created, and only then allow the user to select menu items 2 and 3. And yes, you need to create the circle outside of the `switch`, in a more general scope.

Comment: Ah alright, thank you! Understand that the design itself doesn't make much sense, but am just trying out different things here to see what's works and what doesn't.